# printing hebrew in python works in eclipse but not shell

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

I have some code that converts a Unicode representation of hebrew text file into hebrew for display

for example:

```
f = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in f:
    print eval('u"' + line +'"')
```

This works fun when I run it in PyDev (eclipse), but when I run it from the command line, I get

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 9-10: ordinal not in range(256)
```

An example line from the input file is:

```
\u05d9\u05d5\u05dd
```

What is the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Why use `eval` and not `.decode()`? Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Something is missing from your code; is there a print statement in there too when the error occurs? What is the full traceback?

Comment: The problem is that the terminal uses the wrong encoding, while PyDev is probably "unicode aware". Which terminal are you testing this on?

Comment: I'm using Terminator in linux ubuntu 12.04. How can I get the terminal  to be "unicode aware"?

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `eval()`; instead use the `unicode_escape` codec to interpret that data:

```
for line in f:
    line = line.decode('unicode_escape')
```

The `unicode_escape` encoding interprets `\uabcd` character sequences the same way Python would when parsing a unicode literal in the source code:

```
>>> '\u05d9\u05d5\u05dd'.decode('unicode_escape')
u'\u05d9\u05d5\u05dd'
```

The exception you see is *not* caused by the `eval()` statement though; I suspect it is being caused by an attempt to print the result instead. Python will try to encode `unicode` values automatically and will detect what encoding the current terminal uses.

Your Eclipse output window uses a different encoding from your terminal; if the latter is configured to support Latin-1 then you'll see that exact exception, as Python tries to encode Hebrew codepoints to an encoding that doesn't support those:

```
>>> u'\u05d9\u05d5\u05dd'.encode('latin1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(256)
```

The solution is to reconfigure your terminal (UTF-8 would be a good choice), or to not print `unicode` values with codepoints that cannot be encoded to Latin-1.

If you are redirecting output from Python to a file, then Python cannot determine the output encoding automatically. In that case you can use the [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) to tell Python what encoding to use for standard I/O:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python yourscript.py > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! how do I configure the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this solved my problem.

```
line.decode('unicode_escape')
```

did the trick.

Followup - This now works, but if I try to send the output to a file:

```
python myScript.py > textfile.txt
```

The file itself has the error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 42-44: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: don't put questions in the answer. [Update your question or create a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14663059/edit) instead. Run `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python myScript.py > textfile.txt`